# Getting Error while installing java8 on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu-16.04

I tried to install java 8 on ubuntu 16.04.
The steps followed are :

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt install oracle-java8-installer
```

while running `sudo apt install oracle-java8-installer` I got the below error.

```
dpkg: error processing package unattended-upgrades (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
Errors were encountered while processing:
 openjdk-8-jre-headless:amd64
 locales
 oracle-java8-installer
 linux-image-4.4.0-78-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-78-generic
 linux-image-generic
 linux-generic
 openjdk-8-jre:amd64
 postgresql-common
 postgresql-9.6
 postgresql-contrib-9.6
 postgresql-contrib
 sysstat
 tomcat8
 unattended-upgrades
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Please suggest me how to overcome by this error on Ubuntu and suggest the steps to install oracle-java8.

Comment: try installing it with aptitude or synaptic package manager

Answer (score 1):

Open Terminal -> and do the following steps sequentially:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:openjdk-r/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
```

and finally type:`java -version`.
This command will show you whether jdk installed in your Ubuntu or not.